# Git workflow maintaining commits across development and release branches

Tags: git

Currently our repository consists of branches like the following:

- master -- development branch
- v1.0 -- release branch
- v1.1 -- release branch

Currently once we create a release branch off of master, and say I had a change on master that should also go on the release branch, I'd have to `cherry-pick` the commit onto the release branch.

This is mostly OK except that `cherry-pick` causes the commit hash to change, making it rather hard to refer to a particular commit when communicating with other team members, as well as difficult to tell which branches a commit is present in.

Because commits related to future releases might be present in master, we can't simply merge master onto the release branch whenever a change is made.

Is there a particular git workflow that can get around this issue? Or maybe something we can change about our workflow that would avoid it?

If it helps, this is a private repo with <10 developers.

Comment: You could be doing at least `git cherry-pick -x ...` which appends a line that says "(cherry picked from commit …​)" to the original commit message.

Comment: can't you fork from the last common commit and then merge this branch into the three branches ? This is verbose, but the hash would be the same. Some conflicts may arise also.

Comment: @Yirkha - Didn't know about that, it would certainly be better than nothing.

Comment: @CristianoAraujo - Verbose in the sense that a merge commit would be created in every branch? So far master has been "clean" in the sense that it is always rebased with no merge commits, is there any way to maintain that state?

Comment: Yeah, you would have merge commits in the master, but your history would  point always to the same commit.